# How to create startProcess with a specific priority

Tags: nim-lang

I am using `startProcess` from [osproc](https://nim-lang.org/docs/osproc.html) to create a process but it seems that the priority is hardcoded in the source code to normal. How to start a process with a lower priority?

I've tried to copy paste `startProcess` with a specific priority in my source code but have errors I do not know how to deal with. I also tried to call [winlean.createProcessA(...)](https://nim-lang.org/docs/winlean.html#createProcessW%2CWideCString%2CWideCString%2Cptr.SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES%2Cptr.SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES%2CWINBOOL%2Cint32%2CWideCString%2CWideCString%2CSTARTUPINFO%2CPROCESS_INFORMATION) but get undeclared identifier.

Any idea?

Comment: Could you share your call to `createProcessA()`? Maybe you have to use `createProcessW()` instead.

Comment: the proc in winlean is createProcessW, looks like that has the priority argument, but i'm not windowsy enough to know how to use it